# Optimize large number of images to upload

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-image-picture-crop library to select large number of images(around 100 images) to upload onto the server. And I need to optimize each image and bring down the size to around 100KB. Is there is tool or way to get this done?

Comment: You can compress image before  upload with image compressor package - https://github.com/Shobbak/react-native-compressor

Comment: You can compress image before  upload with image compressor package - https://github.com/Shobbak/react-native-compressor